# Inhomogeneous ODE (2nd order) - question to Laplace-transformation?

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I've the following inhomogeneous second order ODE:

$$a_1\cdot u(t) + a_2\cdot u'(t) + a_3\cdot u''(t) = b_1\cdot y(t) + b_2\cdot y'(t) + b_3\cdot y''(t)$$

The parameters $a_i$ and $b_i$ are constants.

The function $u(t)$ is given by:

$$u(t) = r_0 + r_f\cdot t$$

where $r_0$ and $r_f$ are known constants.

The equation should be solved for an arbitrary time-step $t_2 - t_1$ for $y(t_2, t_1) = \dots$. Therefore I want to use the Laplace-transformation. 
How can I do this?

The given initial conditions which are actually also constants are:

- $u(t_1) = k_0$ and $u'(t_1) = k_f$
- $y(t_1) = y_0$ and $y'(t_1) = y_f$

At first, I thougt that due to the given function $u(t)$ which is actually linear - $u''(t)$ must be equal to **zero.** So my equation is now:

$$a_1\cdot u(t) + a_2\cdot u'(t) = b_1\cdot y(t) + b_2\cdot y'(t) + b_3\cdot y''(t)$$

How do I perform the Laplace-Transformation for the left side of the equation? Normally it must be something like:

$$ a_1\cdot\mathcal{L}\{u\}(s)+a_2\cdot\bigl[s\cdot\mathcal{L\{u\}(s)- k_0}\bigr] = \dots$$

At the end of the solution (due to inverse Laplace transformation), this might lead to a convolution integral.

Is it somehow possible to avoid this? I thought there must be something, because I know the function $u(t)$ ... or do I misunderstand something?

It would be great, if someone can help me ...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: why do you take the second derivative of $u(t)$ and then leave the derivative for $u'$? surely not replacing u is the way forward?

Comment: @Chinny84 how do you mean?

Comment: $$\mathcal{L}\left(b_1y + b_2y' + b_3y''\right) = \mathcal{L}\left(a_1k_0 +a_2k_f + a_1k_f t\right)$$ instead of taking the laplace of the derivative of $u$. Just write it out explicitly..it will all work out but it is surely easier to take lapalce of $\alpha + \beta t$, no?

Comment: @Chinny84 - yep, that's the thing i was thinking of. But what do u mean with "...it is surely easier to take laplace of $\alpha + \beta t$" - I've got my wires crossed somewhere :/

Comment: ah..i just read your question properly. You are not just trying to solve with given $u(t)$ as in solving it from $t=0$.

Comment: @Chinny84 I'll just note that with a change of time variables, you can move the transform to start at $t_1$ so that your derivative rules look like $\mathcal{L^*}\{u'(t)\} = s\mathcal{L^*}\{u(t)\}-u(t_1)$, where $\mathcal{L^*}$ is this time-shifted Laplace operator.